# Email verification with Next js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am building a web application in which i need to verify the user's email sent via the client side (React.js and Next.js) and i'm following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7yFXKsMD_U&t=4796s&ab_channel=CongarProgramming). However, the mentor is using create-react-app CLI and React-Router-Dom for the routing system which doesn't really go with my current needs.

Moreover, I found this method online using HOC :

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';

const login = '/register?redirected=true'; // Define your login route address.

const checkUserAuthentication = () => {
return { auth: null }; // change null to { isAdmin: true } for test it.
};

export default WrappedComponent => {
const hocComponent = ({ ...props }) => <WrappedComponent {...props} />;

hocComponent.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
const userAuth = await checkUserAuthentication();

// Are you an authorized user or not?
if (!userAuth?.auth) {
  // Handle server-side and client-side rendering.
  if (context.res) {
    context.res?.writeHead(302, {
      Location: login,
    });
    context.res?.end();
  } else {
    Router.replace(login);
  }
} else if (WrappedComponent.getInitialProps) {
  const wrappedProps = await WrappedComponent.getInitialProps({...context, auth: userAuth});
  return { ...wrappedProps, userAuth };
}

return { userAuth };
};

 return hocComponent;
};
```

The code above helps me to have a private route that the user cannot access unless he's authenticated (currently no programming included), but on the other hand i still need a page in the following route :

```
'pages/user/activate/[token].js' // the link sent via email from express back end.
```

What i need now is to create this page using Next routing system in order to get the token and decode it to move forward with the back end and save the user into MongoDB, and in order to accomplish that, i have created my `[token].js` page with the following code :

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { authenticate, isAuth } from '../helpers/auth';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const Activate = ({ match }) => {
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  email: '',
  token: '',
  show: true
});
const { email, token, show } = formData;
useEffect(() => {
  let token = match.params.token;
  let { email } = jwt.decode(token);

  if (token) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, email, token });
  }
 

  console.log(token, email);
}, [match.params.token]);



return (
    <> 
        {isAuth() ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null}
        <p>Account activated, please log in</p>
    </>
)
};

export default Activate;
```

However, i keep getting this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
at Activate (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\.next\server\pages\user\activate\[token].js:245:13)
at processChild (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom- 
server.node.development.js:3353:14)
at resolve (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom- 
server.node.development.js:3270:5)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react- 
dom-server.node.development.js:3753:22)
at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom- 
server.node.development.js:3690:29)
at renderToString (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom- 
server.node.development.js:4298:27)
at Object.renderPage (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\next\dist\next- 
server\server\render.js:53:851)
at Function.getInitialProps (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\.next\server\pages\_document.js:293:19)
at loadGetInitialProps (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\next\dist\next- 
server\lib\utils.js:5:101)
at renderToHTML (C:\Users\Hp\Desktop\SMP\client\node_modules\next\dist\next- 
server\server\render.js:53:1142)
```

I couldn't find a solution because i believe that i'm doing something wrong whether in my code or in the logic implemented.

Is there any way that i can do this properly ?

Thank you in advance !